# Couchbase Generic Repository in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, couchbase

I am having one frustrating time attempting to follow the Couchbase documentation (which is horribly outdated and the examples just do not even compile).

I already have several other persistence stacks following this same pattern. I would like to migrate to Couchbase from CosmosDb and I simply cannot figure out how to implement this in a generic pattern. FYI, I am not here to debate the move from Cosmos to Couchbase, so the let please leave that topic alone.

I have already done this for Mongo, Dynamo, PostresSql, MsftSql, Cosmos Document, Cosmos SQL, and Cosmos Table.

Nuget Packages:
Couchbase.Lite @ 2.7.1
CouchbaseNetClient @ 3.0.1

The `IPlatformRepository` interface, used by all repositories in the system

```
        Task<T> CreateAsync(T data);

        Task<T> ReadAsync(Guid id);

        Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T data);

        Task<bool> DeleteAsync(Guid id);

        Task<IEnumerable<T>> AllAsync();

        Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null);
```

Here is the PoC code that I have in my Couchbase provider, but I am stuck at trying to figure out how to do the `AllAsync()` and `QueryAsync()` functions (commented out `QueryAsync()` is from the CosmosDocument provider I have. I have not started on that one yet. I started with the `AllAsync()` to just retrieve the documents.

```
    public class CouchbaseRepository<T> : IPlatformRepository<T>
        where T: DomainAggregate
    {
        private readonly string collectionName;
        private readonly CouchbaseSettings couchbaseSettings;
        private ICluster cluster;
        private IBucket bucket;
        private ICollection<T> collection;
        private ICouchbaseCollection cbc;

        public CouchbaseRepository(CouchbaseSettings settings)
        {
            Inflector.Inflector.SetDefaultCultureFunc = () => new CultureInfo("en");
            collectionName = typeof(T).Name.Pluralize().Uncapitalize();
        }

        public async Task<T> ReadAsync(Guid id)
        {
            var result = await bucket.Collection(collectionName).GetAsync(id.ToString());
            return result.ContentAs<T>();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            // var results = new List<T>();
            //
            // var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            //     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
            //         databaseId,
            //         collectionId),
            //     new FeedOptions
            //     {
            //         MaxItemCount = -1,
            //         EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
            //     });
            //
            // predicate = null;
            // var conditionalQuery = predicate == null
            //     ? query
            //     : query.Where(predicate);
            //
            // var documentQuery = conditionalQuery.AsDocumentQuery();
            //
            // while (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
            // {
            //     results.AddRange(await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            // }
            //
            // return results;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> AllAsync()
        {
            using (var cluseter = new Cluster())
            {

            }
        }

        public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T item)
        {
            var result = await bucket.Collection(collectionName).InsertAsync(item.Id.ToString(), item);
            return item;
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T item)
        {
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(Guid id)
        {
        }

        private async Task EstablishConnection()
        {
            cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync(couchbaseSettings.Endpoint, couchbaseSettings.User, couchbaseSettings.Password);
            bucket = await cluster.BucketAsync(couchbaseSettings.Bucket);
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI this question was also posted to the Couchbase forums, and there's discussion there: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/generic-couchbase-repository-pattern-in-net-core-3-1/26105/4

Comment: Thank you @MatthewGroves